# Is there a simple way to know if login has failed Django?

Tags: python, html, django, authentication

I am currently using Django built-in login feature. I only made my own form as you can see on this image:
[Login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xhq1.png)

It is really basic. Only two inputs and some formatting:

```
<form action="#" class="login-form" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-field" placeholder="Username" name="username" required>
    <input type="password" class="form-control input-field" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
</form>
```

When I enter a correct username and password, everything works and I am redirected on the correct page, but when I enter a wrong password, the login page is just reloaded, and nothing tells me the password/username was incorrect.

I understand that, no matter if the password is correct or incorrect, I am redirected on the main page, but when I am not logged in (so when the password is wrong), this main page redirects me on the login page (because it is on login required).

Do you know if there is a simple way to detect if a login failed and display it ?

Comment: yeah just simply use Django message. If you enter wrong password or username it show the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)import view.py
from django.contrib import messages
2)In Login View--

```
 try:
    User.object.get(email=request.Post['email'])
except :
    messages.Error("User Not Found")
```

3)Html file

```
{% if messages %}

  {% for message in messages %}
    <div class="alert alert-{% ifequal message.tags 'error' %}danger {% else %}{{ message.tags }} {% endifequal%} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        {{ message }}
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </button>
    </div>
    {% endfor %} 
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the thing is that I don't have a login view, I am using the Django built-in feature. I just want to have a better login page :(

Comment: then you can simple ajax post request

Answer (score 0):

in login html

```
$("#login_form").on("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  data = {
    "email": $("#id_email").val(),
    "password": $("#id_password").val(),
  };
  if (data){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: `${URL}/user/login/`,
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
           Swal.fire({
              title:  data.success,
              icon: 'success',
              confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            }).then((result) => {
               window.location =`${URL}`
            })
        },
        error: function (err) {
          Swal.fire({
              title:  err["responseJSON"]["error"],
              icon: 'error',
              confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            }).then((result) => {
            })
        },
      });
  }
```

});

in login view

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(email=request.POST['email'])
        user = authenticate(request, username=request.POST['email'],
                                password=request.POST['password'])
        if user is not None:
            auth_login(request, user)   
            return JsonResponse({"success": 'Successfully User Login.'}, status=200)
    except:
        return JsonResponse({"error": str(request.POST['email'])+' is not registered with us'}, status=400)
return render(request, 'allauth/account/login.html', {"URL": settings.URL})
```